# Gathering 4 data sets based on the names in row

Tags: r

I have 4 data sets like below:

```
> dput(data1)
structure(c("Mark_1_Rep_Mean", "Chris_1_Rep_Mean", "Tom_3_Rep_Mean", 
            "Eric_1_Rep_Mean", "Marcel_2_Rep_Mean", "Grant_1_Rep_Mean", 
            "Mark_1_Rep1", "Chris_1_Rep1", "Tom_3_Rep1", "Eric_1_Rep1", 
            "Marcel_2_Rep1", "Grant_1_Rep1", "27772867.153991", "37880613.0075859", 
            "17708404.9082011", "8688739.67922574", "5728817.17146037", "3828066.3503363"
), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("vec_gather", "vec_gather", 
                                        "vec_gather", "vec_gather", "vec_gather", "vec_gather"), c("Rep_Mean", 
                                                                                                   "Rep1", "AUC_Rep1")))

> dput(data2)
structure(c("Nina_1_Rep_Mean", "Chris_1_Rep_Mean", "Tim_3_Rep_Mean", 
            "Eric_1_Rep_Mean", "Marcel_2_Rep_Mean", "Grant_1_Rep_Mean", 
            "Nina_1_Rep1", "Chris_1_Rep1", "Tim_3_Rep1", "Eric_1_Rep1", 
            "Marcel_2_Rep1", "Grant_1_Rep1", "3291992.02338316", "2551728.32427674", 
            "2979707.83155071", "6171673.62102796", "6931956.13708179", "3778083.59661274"
), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("vec_AGI_mono", "vec_gather", 
                                        "vec_gather", "vec_gather", "vec_gather", "vec_gather"), c("Rep_Mean", 
                                                                                                   "Rep2", "AUC_Rep2")))

> dput(data3)
structure(c("Mark_1_Rep_Mean", "Tim_1_Rep_Mean", "Tom_3_Rep_Mean", 
            "Eric_1_Rep_Mean", "Marcel_2_Rep_Mean", "John_1_Rep_Mean", 
            "Mark_1_Rep1", "Tim_1_Rep1", "Tom_3_Rep1", "Eric_1_Rep1", 
            "Marcel_2_Rep1", "John_1_Rep1", "3639230.51627098", "2879829.23738129", 
            "1529562.30387159", "1963745.90759888", "1975191.01828114", "2663188.06544836"
), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("vec_AGI_mono", "vec_gather", 
                                        "vec_gather", "vec_gather", "vec_gather", "vec_gather"), c("Rep_Mean", 
                                                                                                   "Rep3", "AUC_Rep3")))

> dput(data4)
structure(c("Mark_1_Rep_Mean", "Chris_1_Rep_Mean", "Tom_3_Rep_Mean", 
            "Eric_2_Rep_Mean", "John_2_Rep_Mean", "Grant_1_Rep_Mean", 
            "Mark_1_Rep1", "Chris_1_Rep1", "Tom_3_Rep1", "Eric_1_Rep1", 
            "John_2_Rep1", "Grant_1_Rep1", "7320549.56504402", "2478231.1406273", 
            "2839730.47826704", "2410237.25323096", "31706460.4100607", "30098040.5281682"
), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("vec_AGI_mono", "vec_gather", 
                                        "vec_gather", "vec_gather", "vec_gather", "vec_gather"), c("Rep_Mean", 
                                                                                                   "Rep4", "AUC_Rep4")))
```

I would like to merge them to one table but on specific conditions. First of all I would like to take all the possible names from those data sets (first column):

```
vec_rep1 <- data1[,1]
vec_rep2 <- data2[,1]
vec_rep3 <- data3[,1]
vec_rep4 <- data4[,1]

vec_all <- unique(c(vec_rep1, vec_rep2, vec_rep3, vec_rep4)
```

That would be the first column in my new table. Now I would like to assign the other columns from the 4 data sets I have. The script should look for each of the name from the first column in a new table (the unique names which we extracted in the first step) in each of the data sets and put the next columns. Of course not all the names can be find in all of the replicates (data sets) so if something is missing put just `NA` in the table.

Desired output:

```
Rep_Mean               Rep1               AUC_Rep1      Rep2        AUC_Rep2          Rep3            AUC_Rep3          Rep4            AUC_Rep4
"AT1G01050_1_Rep_Mean" "NA or name" "NA or number"    "NA or name"  "NA or number"   "NA or name"     "NA or number"    "NA or name"      "NA or number"
"AT1G01080_1_Rep_Mean" "NA or name" "NA or number "   "NA or name"  "NA or number"   "NA or name"     "NA or number"    "NA or name"     "NA or number"
"AT1G01080_3_Rep_Mean" "NA or name" "NA or number"    "NA or name"  "NA or number"   "NA or name"     "NA or number"    "NA or name"     "NA or number"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `full_join` function of `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(full_join(full_join(as.data.frame.matrix(data1),as.data.frame.matrix(data2)),as.data.frame.matrix(data3)),as.data.frame.matrix(data4))
```